# How to fix this JavasScript to change the sequence of div tags on my webpage?

Tags: jquery

I need to move around a div tag with wpf-topic-tags, so it shows just above the div tag with wpf-topic-form-wrap.
I have tried using these 3 lines of code and none of them seems to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wpf-topic-tags').remove().insertBefore('.wpf-topic-form-wrap');
jQuery('.wpf-topic-tags').prependTo('.wpf-topic-form-wrap');
jQuery('.wpf-topic-tags').insertBefore('.wpf-topic-form-wrap');
```

});

I will appreciate if someone can please point me in the same direction.

Thanks.

PS: In case useful, I have wpForo like this https://wpforo.com/community/add-topic/8/ and I am trying to move the Tags field to be moved to show just before the Title field.

Comment: I can not access the form . I don't understand what you need ?

Comment: you are removing the element before moving it. maybe you can remove the entire first line as you don't want to remove it but only to move it.

Answer (score 0):

To move an element you can not remove it. You only need one line of code from javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wpf-topic-tags').insertBefore('.wpf-topic-form-wrap');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="wpf-topic-form-wrap">
<div>This inside a form element</div>
</form>

<div class="wpf-topic-tags"><h1>wpf-topic-tags</h1></div>
```

and without the javascript line the "wpf-topic-tag" will remain at the bottom

```html
<form class="wpf-topic-form-wrap">
<div>This inside a form element</div>
</form>

<div class="wpf-topic-tags"><h1>wpf-topic-tags</h1></div>
```